Quasiconvexity implies rank-one convexity proof
I'm struggling to understand the proof of Proposition 5.3 in Rindler's 'Calculus of Variations'. 

I cannot follow why $u_j$ is $0$ on the boundary of $Q_n$.

The next line states that $u_j$ converges weak* to $Fx$ in $W^{1, \infty}$. This seems believable but I am unsure on the details of the derivatives, and specifically if the geometry of the cube is necessary for this.



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
